# PHP Get html inside html

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get part of a html text. I'm trying to get each separate list contained under the h3 tags and the images at the bottom.Here is the sample text:

Any help would be great.

Thank you

```
<h3>Item Summary</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam dictum adipiscing nulla. Aenean id leo non urna sollicitudin lobortis. Sed malesuada diam ut elit accumsan auctor. Proin nisl orci, tempor sed pulvinar ut, semper id nisl. Quisque pellentesque porta facilisis. Duis vestibulum pellentesque commodo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla facilisi. Etiam eget lacus mauris, non accumsan erat. Etiam gravida posuere sollicitudin. Cras id sodales diam. </p>
<h3>Item Features</h3>
<ul>
<li>Feature 1.</li>
<li>Feature 2.</li>
<li>Feature 3.</li>
<li>Feature 4.  </li>
<li>Feature 5.</li>
</ul>
<h3>Item Details</h3>
<ul>
<li>Detail 1</li>
<li>Detail 2</li>
<li>Detail 3</li>
<li>Detail 4</li>
<li>Detail 5</li>
</ul>
<h3>Contact Information</h3>
<ul>
<li>Contact 1</li>
<li>Contact 2</li>
<li>Contact 3</li>
<li>Contact 4</li>

</ul>
<p >
   <img height="100px" src="http://www.mydomain.com/Images/123456.jpg" width="200px"/>
</p>
<p >
   <img height="100px" src="http://www.mydomain.com/Images/123456.jpg" width="200px"/>
</p>
<p >
   <img height="100px" src="http://www.mydomain.com/Images/123456.jpg" width="200px"/>
</p>
<p >
   <img height="100px" src="http://www.mydomain.com/Images/123456.jpg" width="200px"/>
</p>
<p >
   <img height="100px" src="http://www.mydomain.com/Images/123456.jpg" width="200px"/>
</p>

      <img alt="img1" src="000.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Would you mind to elaborate. Not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you extracting data from someone else's page?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [tag:xpath] rather than [tag:regex].

Answer (score 5):

Dont use a regex, use a DOM parser like DOMDocument or SimpleXMLElement.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($yourHTML);

$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);

//Get all lists:
$lists = $finder->query('//ul');

// get all lists immediately AFTER h3's
$listsAfterHeader = $finder->query('//h3/following-sibling::ul[position()=1]');
```